# How to detect Property and its value in Autofac xml file?

Tags: xml, properties, configuration, autofac

I wish to set the boolen property to true/false in xml file, which I then add using ConfigurationBuilder using autofac.
Code as below

`var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();`
`configurationBuilder.AddXmlFile(@".\SomeFile.xml");`

In this xml file, I want to add some boolean properties that can be set to true/false. Then read those values and do respective task. I am not sure how to structure the xml file.

Comment: Where have you looked for answers? Have you [read the docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html)? Have you looked at the [Autofac configuration source](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Configuration), including the [unit tests and included file examples](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Configuration/tree/develop/test/Autofac.Configuration.Test/Files)?

Comment: Yes I did. I found some configuration for Json file but not for xml. Comnverting json to xml did not help.

Comment: There are XML files in the unit test source.